# Angular 2 nav treeview ng2-tree doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, treeview

me again.

I'm trying to use the following plugin: ng2-tree https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-tree. 
It is supposed to have a demo, I asked the guy who created in the issue page on the github but he hasn't answered.

If I'm not wrong, if I go to the demo folder and open the index.html file it's supposed to show me the same page as this example: http://valor-software.com/ng2-tree/ but I get a 'Loading' stuff and nothing else.

Thanks for helping me!!

Comment: Are you trying in `angular 1.x`?

Comment: It is angular 2

Comment: what do u want exactly.either demo or code?